# Unknown symbol showing on developer console - react

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am getting this Symbol ( Æ’ ) on my React components area, next to props description. What does that mean?
When I try to search for this on google, it just transforms it to "ae" letters..

[image of the symbol in the developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjJR8.png)